# How can I store the date to the table without a time stamp?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am in a form, using Short Date format (I have tried General, Long, Medium) - each stores a time stamp along with the date in the table. like x/xx/xxxx hr:min:ss am/pm.

This should be so simple.

Comment: Access does not have a "date only" data type.  The Date/Time data type *always* includes a time component.

Comment: I feel less stupid, but how sad....

Comment: No need to worry about how it's stored. The points you can control are how it's presented and edited in your form's controls.

Comment: Yeah, the closest you can get to what you want for the stored values is to make midnight the time piece for those Date/Time values.  And in some contexts, Access will then display only the date piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments to your question, values in Access `Date/Time` columns always have both a date and a time component. However, in most cases Access will display only the date part if the time is exactly midnight, so if you force the time to midnight when storing the value then it will look like a date-only value.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the Date value to Integer you can hide the time portion of the Date and Time.

Example:

dValue = Now() shows Date and Time

dValue = Int(Now()) shows only the Date